# Proving the set equality $B - A = B\cap A^C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

For all sets $A$ and $B,(B-A)=B\cap A^C$.

I would like to know if this proof is correct or if I am on the right track. Here it is:

Let $b \in B$ such that $b \notin A$ than $b \in B$ and $b \in A^C$. Thus $(B-A)\subseteq B\cap A^C$ Next suppose $b\in B$ and $b \notin A$ than by definition of difference of two sets this is just $B-A$ and $B \cap A^C \subseteq (B-A)$. We conclude that $(B-A)=B \cap A^C$.

Comment: Define $B-A \equiv B\cap A^C$.  Then you're done.

Comment: It is right, but I would simplify it because - in this case - starting from $b \in B$ and $b \notin A$, you may proceed with "equivalences" (i.e.$\leftrightarrow$); thus, you do not have really to repeat two times the same argument.

Comment: I don't think I can use that statement if I am trying to prove it.

Comment: You're missing punctuation and you misspelled "then".  Also, on your converse proof (the second one), you didn't start with $b \in A^C$ but instead $b \notin A$.

Comment: @Mauro Allegranza So I can just write $b\in B$ such that $b \notin A$ iff $b\in B$ and $b \in A^C$ and than make my conclusion from there?

Comment: $b \in (B-A) \iff b \in B \text{ and } b\notin A \iff b \in B \cap A^C$ I simplified it to a very simple proof.

Comment: YES, right ! : $b \in (B−A)$ is by def $b \in B$ and $b \notin A$ : so you must use equivalence. But again, $b \notin A$ is by def $b \in A^C$ and also in this case you are allowed to use equivalence. Last step : from $b \in B$ and $b \in A^C$ with the fact that by definition : $B \cap A^C = \{ x : x \in B \land x \in A^C \}$ we may conclude with $b \in B \cap A^C$.

Answer (score 3):

Your reasoning is correct, and the equivalence you give in the comments:

$$b \in (B-A) \iff b \in B \text{ and } b\notin A \iff b \in B \cap A^C$$

is an even shorter version of the same proof. Cheers!

Comment: I don't get what value your first comment is adding. Isn't that what answering does, which is evident by your post being an answer, and what motive you have is a bit irrelevant?

Comment: Hm, you're quite right. It's an old habit, I suppose. Thanks for questioning it :).

Comment: btw, on the topic I wouldn't make it a community wiki either. on SO they're sort of deprecated, and I think it's valuable for you to get credit for the answer, even if your added value is simply rolling up comments into an answer, firstly because that's good practice and should be encouraged, and secondly because as far as future visitors are concerned you did the *real* work here. </meta>

Comment: I'll consider that as well. But really I don't care for the rep, so CW seems like a good way of assuring that I'm not "rep-whoring".